# How to avoid sql formatting when saving views on DBeaver?

Tags: mysql, database, view, formatting, dbeaver

I'm using DBeaver in a MySQL database, every time I save a databade view it changes the SQL format to a very confusing format adding a lot of quotes and parentesis

Original:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcXuc.png)

After Save:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORLHR.png)

How can I avoid it?

I would like to keep the original format.